# Is it possible to modify a Github repo's contents at a previous commit and then link to that modified commit in requirements.txt?

Tags: github, requirements.txt

I'm currently pulling in a repo at a previous commit with:

```
git+git://github.com/username/application-name.git@357y3530u325#egg=application-name
```

I want to modify some code at that commit, so I have forked the repo.

Is it possible to modify a Github repo's contents at a previous commit and then link to that modified commit in requirements.txt?

It would be good if I could do it all via the Github website, as opposed to cloning to local, modifying and pushing etc, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a branch in your fork of the repository, make your changes and push them back into your branch on Github. Then change the repository specification (including commit number or branch name) to point to that.

Comment: For reference: I 1) went to forked repo 2) clicked on `n commits` 3) located the desired commit and clicked on the `<>` icon 4) clicked on the `tree` dropdown and added new branch name to input area 5) went to desired commit again and clicked on the `Compare & pull request` button 6) i then had to select my forked repo as the `base` and `compare` it to the new branch 7) it said next to this: `Able to merge` 8) and then clicked `Create pull request` 9) It then said `This branch has no conflicts with the base branch` and I clicked on `Merge pull request` (continued)...

Comment: 9) It then said `Pull request successfully merged and closed` and `You're all set--the new-branch-name branch can be safely deleted` 10) I then clicked on Delete branch button (that was a mistake I think, read on) 11)  It seemed it had just added the changes to the most recent commit of the fork, so I navigated back to the page where I could see `Restore deleted branch` and restored it 12) From the forked repo page, I could then select the modified branch (which is at the desired older commit point) and get the url and reference it in `requirements.txt` as: (continued)...

Comment: `git+git://github.com/username/application-name@modified-branch name#egg=application-name` 13)  The import from `requirements.txt` then worked as desired.